# Too many redirects

Tags: bug

When I'm on my profile page and click on *link my stack exchange account* link it gives me response code 310 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I'm using Google Chrome and already did an hard refresh, still the same problem.

Note: there were previous questions related to these problem, but long ago, and the solution is always something on Stack's servers, so hope this can notify them there's a problem.

Comment: What is "link my stack exchange account"? Never saw such a thing. Do you mean the "network profile" link? Do you mean the "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" button in edit profile?

Comment: No I meant linking one of my StackExchange account to my StackCarreers account.
At that time when I clicked and that error occurred, but I don't have it anymore, not really sure why.

Comment: Still can't see any "link my stack exchange account" in Careers as well can you please post screenshot of what you mean?